# Use PHP to move files in Windows CMD

Tags: php, windows, cmd

i've tried to do some commands via PHP in Windows CMD.

The basic as execute programs and run ping with output for example, was done fine.

But when i try to run the folow command, i can't complete..it's possible to do that?

```
<?php
$iduser = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$output = shell_exec("move C:\[PATH TO FILE]\"".$iduser.".json C:\[PATH TO]\destination");
echo $output;
?>
```

If it's not possible through this method, there's another way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to invoke a shell when PHP already has a COPY function? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Comment: I'm going to assume that your double-quoting is incorrect here, `C:\[PATH TO FILE]\"".$iduser.".json`, especially because doublequotes are invalid characters in file and directory names, and you have an odd number of them.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, solved.